# talend sum of values

Tags: talend, data-integration

I'm using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration. I have two tables (.csv files):

Table 1:

```
Date             Values
01-04-2017         4
02-04-2017         5
03-04-2017         6
04-04-2017         7
```

Table 2:

```
    Date         Values
03-04-2017         10
04-04-2017         12
05-04-2017         15
06-04-2017         18
```

I want to get a single output table that is outer-joins on dates, and sums up values for common dates (there are some dates present in Table 1 and Table 2 only, and common dates across both the tables):
Expected Output

```
Date             Values
01-04-2017         4
02-04-2017         5
03-04-2017         16
04-04-2017         19
05-04-2017         15
06-04-2017         18
```

I tried using tmap and tjoin but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use tUnite to merge data from the 2 flows then tAggregateRow to sum values by date.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this..

In talend, tMysqlInput ------->tLogRow

for tMysqlInput use the query:

`"select Date,sum(Values) as Values from (select * from table1 union select * from table2)t group by Date"`

Then you will get the required result..:)

[image]

[image]

[image]